# What this error stands for and how to fix it?

Tags: java, python, exception, jython

I'm jython/python bukkit plugin coder and I'm getting weird error.. I'm trying to recode something that's already done (in Java) in Python... Here's the java part of code:

```
    HashMap<Player, String> channelList = new HashMap<Player, String>();
    public void useChannel(Player p, String format, String channel){
    if(channel == "main"){
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage(format);
    } else {
          Player[] online = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers();
          for(int a = 0; a <= online.length - 1; a++){
              if(channelList.get(online[a]) == channel){
                  online[a].sendMessage("*" + format);
              }
          }
    }
}

@EventHandler
public void onChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event){
    event.setCancelled(true);
    String channel = event.getMessage().substring(0, 1);
    String userChannel = "";
    switch(channel){
    case "!": userChannel = "spanish";
    case "?": userChannel = "french";
    case "@": userChannel = "dutch";
    case "$": userChannel = "spanish";
    default: userChannel = "main";     
    }
    useChannel(event.getPlayer(), event.getFormat(), userChannel);
}
```

}

and here's what I made in python/jython (have on mind that this maybe is not same and that's the cause of error):

```
    channelList = HashMap()

    def useChannel(self):
    format = event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent.getFormat()    
    if(channel == "main"):
      Bukkit.broadcastMessage(format)
    else:
        online = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()
        b = online.lenght - 1
        a = 0
        for a in a <= b:
            if channelList.get(online[a]) == channel:
               online[a].sendMessage("* %s"%format)

def balkanChannel(self):
    userChannel = "balkan"
    return userChannel

def germanChannel(self):
    userChannel = "german"
    return userChannel

@hook.event("player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent", "HIGHEST")
def onAsyncPlayerChatEvent(event):
    event.setCancelled(1)
    channel = event.getMessage().substring(0, 1)
    userChannel = ""  
    try:
       options = {
               '!': pyplugin.balkanChannel,
               '$': pyplugin.germanChannel}
       if value in switch:
          switch[value]() 
       else:
           pass
    except KeyError:
          userChannel = "main"
    pyplugin.useChannel(event.getPlayer(), event.getFormat(), userChannel)
```

This is chat-related plugin, which should upon AsyncChatPlayerEvent check if there is ! or $ prefix in message... Those prefixes are done as "cases" in Java, but as far as I know, there is no thing like that in Python, so I've done it this way (which maybe is not right way) ?

Here's the error I get upon chatting with those prefixes ($ and !):

```
14:38:59 [SEVERE] java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 5
>
Exception: org.python.core.PyException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler
in thread "Connection #1 read thread"
```

To sum up, I'm trying to "re-code" above java code to python, but I get some weird error...

Thanks for answering! :)

P.S. server freezes after it spitts error... If you need more informations, just comment...

Comment: in `onAsyncPlayerChatEvent`, what are `value` and `switch`?

Comment: @Vlad regardless of that, I just realised it spitts same error whenever I use that event? Do you know what that error talks about, since there is no any traces...

Comment: the `PyException` has a [traceback](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/PyException.html#traceback) associated, but I have no clue how to use it. Easiest thing to do is you could wrap everything in a `try` statement with an `except Exception, e: print e.message` at the end.

Comment: @Vlad tried it like this:

http://pastebin.com/EdLERw3Y
but it returns same error..

Comment: If you want to access the exception as `e`, you want `except Exception, e` instead of `except Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, sorry. I was using wrong event...

I was using AsyncPlayerChatEvent instead of regular PlayerChatEvent...